# change global variable at runtime for imported function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am trying to make functions in different files of a larger program send a message to each other. There is a function without a return statement. In a test example, if I do the following in one file, I can change a global variable and detect its change at run time:

**one_file.py**

```
import time
import threading
has_run = False

def processing_function():
    global has_run
    time.sleep(5)
    has_run = True

start = time.clock()

thread = threading.Thread(target=processing_function)
thread.start()

while True:
    print(has_run)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if (10/3600) < time.clock() - start:
        break
```

When run, this will print False for a while then start printing True.

I tried to get this to work across two files like this:

**file1.py**

```
import time
has_run = False

def processing_function():
    global has_run
    time.sleep(5)
    has_run = True
```

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import processing_function, has_run
import time
import threading

start = time.clock()
thread = threading.Thread(target=processing_function)
thread.start()

while True:
    print(has_run)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if (10/3600) < time.clock() - start:
        break
```

If you now run file2.py, it only prints False a lot of times.

Why is this imported global variable not being modified by the running process, and how can this be refactored so it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import the name `has_run`, you have created a new global in the current module named `has_run` that refers to the same object as `file1.has_run`, but an *assignment* to one of the names does not affect the other. If you want to see the changes made by `processing_function`, you need to continue accessing the name through the module.

```
while True:
    print(file1.has_run)
    ...
```

(This is because `processing_function` assigns a new value to its global, rather than mutating an existing value.)

You can observe this through  a much simpler example. Consider a very simple module `tmp1`:

```
x = 3
```

Now see how `from tmp1 import x` creates a global variable whose value remains independent of `tmp1.x`:

```
>>> import tmp1
>>> from tmp1 import x
>>> x
3
>>> tmp1.x
3
>>> x = 6
>>> tmp1.x
3
>>> tmp1.x = 5
>>> tmp1.x
5
>>> x
6
>>>
```

Comment: Seems like a `Lock` would also be required to control concurrent access to the global variable.

Comment: True, but I'd like to keep this answer focused strictly on the scoping issue. The race condition is really a separate question.

Comment: @chepner thanks, it works. I changed the import statement in file2 to be just `import file1` and changed the two places to be accessed through dots as per your answer. I will reflect on why this worked, as I proceed to implement it in the rest of the code, but your "detached" argument sounds intuitively correct.

Comment: chepner: You're also completely glossing over the fact that what you say in your answer about "detaching" is only true for immutable objects. If the variable was, say, a `list`, it wouldn't be necessary to reference it through its module name. In other words, I think you may have "dumbed down" your answer too much.

Comment: @martineau For *assignments*, it doesn't matter; the names `tmp1.x` and `x` are simply different, and assignments to one do not affect assignments to the other. Since the names initially *refer* to the same object (I should edit my answer to emphasize that), then the result of *mutating* that object would be visible via either name.

Comment: I don't think you understood the point of my last comment—which was that if `x` was a `list` defined in `file1.py`, and `file2.py` did a `from file1 import x`, then changing plain `x` in file2 (i.e. `x[0] = 42`) _would_ affect its value globally since `list`s are mutable. That would not be the case if `x` was an `int` (which would become "detached"). P.S. I just verified this using Python 3.7.0.

Comment: @martineau That's not an assignment (though syntactically, it looks like one). You aren't assigning a new value to the name `x`, you're calling `x.__setitem__(0, 42)` to mutate the object *referenced* by `x`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the details of sharing the variable between Threads in Python you can find in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774768/python-creating-a-shared-variable-between-threads).

Essentially, sharing any state (incl. variable) between threads requires synchronization (e.g. using `threading.Condition`). Otherwise, you are risking a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) between one or more threads competing for access to the variable.

Comment: There may be a subtle race condition, but you can reproduce the problem (one of scoping) without the use of threads at all.