# How to share a variable that can be updated among all threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am currently writing a script where I want to store the headers and cookies whenever there is a detection of the website where I require to solve my very own created solution to login. Once the login is solved, I want to store the session into with the proxy. This is what I have written

```
from threading import Thread

import test_by_me

# Save the session to a dict to be re-used
saved_session: dict = {}


def injection(session, response):
    if test_by_me.challenge(session, response):
        solve = test_by_me.solve(session, response)

        # Save the session to a dict to be re-used
        saved_session[session.proxies["https"]] = {
            "headers": session.headers,
            "cookies": session.cookies
        }

        # Return the response
        return solve
    else:
        return response


def create_session():
    return test_by_me.create_scraper(
        Hook=injection,
    )


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Each thread runs this functions independently
def from_page(url):
    while True:
        with create_session() as session:
            proxy = proxies.random_proxies()  # Returns a single rando proxy format

            session.proxies = {
                'https': proxy.random_proxies()
            }

            if proxy in saved_session:
                session.headers = saved_session[proxy]['headers']
                session.cookies = saved_session[proxy]['cookies']

            # Make sure to have GET inside proxies context manager
            resp = session.get(url, timeout=6)
            ...
```

**main:**

```
def main() -> None:
    db_urls = [...]

    # Start threads for each url in the difference
    for url in db_urls:
        Thread(
            target=from_page(url, )
        ).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However my problem is that I cannot figure out how I can share the variable (saved_session) to all the threads that are being alive so I can re-use the same session if it generates the same proxy in the line `proxy = proxies.random_proxies()` -> if its e.g. 'http://192.168.1.1:1841' and if we have that proxy stored into the saved_session, then I want to re-use the session. how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python creating a shared variable between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774768/python-creating-a-shared-variable-between-threads)

Comment: Hmm not quite @decadenza - Since I believe my issue could hgappend due to I will add/update the dict, maybe there could be an issue regarding concurrent?

Comment: Since save_session is a global mutable object, could you use the method from [How to Share Data explicitly between Threads vs. Processes in Python](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-tips-multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-data-sharing-tutorial-52743ed48825)?  Basically, "When you create a mutable object such as a list or dictionary in the global scope, it shares the same memory address anytime you use it as a thread argument, which is called “Pointer” in lower-level languages like C or C++. "

Comment: @DarrylG I see, I do understand but I cannot see how that would possible work with my code that I have provided really, do you perhaps have time to try use my example and see how you meant? I understand that you want to insert the variable (the mutable object) into a args?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie I can't run your example since it's missing some code (e.g. module test_by_me and urls for db_urls.  Is the issue having save_session as an argument for function from_page?  This was just an idea that may not work.

Comment: Dont think its an issue but will it be shareable for every thread if I send as argument though? @DarrylG

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, so was just going by the article I referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not injecting the `session` object to each target thread function and using a [`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) to change shared variables state?

Maybe you don't need to reuse the same session... still I would advise against spawning sessions per-threads, it becomes tricky and inefficient.

```
import threading 

saved_session: dict = {}

lock = threading.Lock()

def from_page(url, session):
    while True:
        proxy = proxies.random_proxies()  # Returns a single rando proxy format
        
        # using lock to change shared variables
        with lock:
            session.proxies = {
                'https': proxy.random_proxies()
            }

            if proxy in saved_session:
                session.headers = saved_session[proxy]['headers']
                session.cookies = saved_session[proxy]['cookies']

        # Make sure to have GET inside proxies context manager
        resp = session.get(url, timeout=6)
        ...

def main() -> None:
    db_urls = [...]
    with create_session() as session:
        # Start threads for each url in the difference
        for url in db_urls:
            Thread(
                target=from_page, args=(url,session, )
            ).start()
```

Comment: But the `saved_session` is still not being used anywhere between the threads?

Comment: How about using a lock to prevent race conditions on ``shared_variables`` ?

Comment: Not sure if I follow? What I meant is that, as you can see the `saved_session` is in a top of the file, is it OK to have it that way - to store and use the values in there?

Comment: I think is good either to pass it as thread args or leave it as global variable, as long as this object is properly protected by any thread it tries to modify it.

Comment: Appreciate that! Then I know what to do :D